# For MQ mutual TLS authentication, how does the certificate relate to the connection parameters?

Tags: ibm-mq, tls1.2

We have a server (IBM i) which hosts a queue manager. We have a third party who connect to this using MQ client software (through a B2B interconnect). This is currently working with TLS but it was set up years ago and I'm trying to fully understand the moving parts because we want to change the certificate on the server.

As I understand things so far:

- The server has a server certificate, issued by our company CA, along with our relevant CA certificates loaded in the server key store.
- The client has a client certificate, issued by *their* company CA, along with their relevant CA certificates loaded in their key store.
- The client and the server have each other's CA certificates loaded.
- The server has a Server Connection Channel with a TLS CipherSpec defined, and a client certificate is required to connect.

What I do *not* understand is the link between what the client attempts to connect to (i.e. a connection string of some kind including a network address for the queue manager) and the server's certificate.

On the web, a server certificate's Common Name *must* match the name at which the web site was accessed. E.g. internally we can access a web server at `https://server/somepage.html` but if the certificate has `server.company.com` as the Common Name, then the browser will report it as insecure. Only using `https://server.company.com/somepage.html` is considered secure by the browser.

In the MQ Client-Server connection, does this relationship also need to be present? We currently have a server certificate with common name `myserver`. I want to change the server to use a different certificate with the common name `myserver.company.com`. *Will this require the client to change their connection string or other configuration value?*

Comment: "In the MQ Client-Server connection, does this relationship also need to be present?" That is mostly up to the client or library used by client choice, even if normally a proper TLS client should indeed match things. So it all depends on that. Obviously the server can't do the same thing, so it can either authorize all certificates from a given CA (but handling revocation list) or it can be preprogrammed with a specific list of certificates (their fingerprints/subject typically) to allow and refuse any other.

Comment: You hypothesis is easy to test though: create a CNAME record in the DNS with any random name pointing to current name and then instruct your client to connect to that new name. If it works, it means the client does not care about mapping between hostname used to connect and hostname in certificate (because they will obviously NOT match), but if you get a TLS error at connection then you have the proof that the name of the server and the name in the certificate do need to match for the client somehow (or the client is just whitelisting the specific certificate)

Comment: Aside, do note that the practice of using the Subject to store server hostnames is deprecated since decades, and even browsers now stop to do this. Server hostnames should be stored in the SAN section, which also allow multiple names in fact, which is extremely useful. Any sane TLS stack today, for hostname verification, should be able to handle the content in the SAN section. Also, while I am there do note that lots of library have a parameter like "ignore hostname verification" (which should be disabled by default, but it exists to be enabled) to bypass mismatches exactly.

Comment: The "easy" test would not be so easy as we are a large company and getting any DNS changes is a bit of an undertaking. But, as you say, the client library is the key and testing may be the only way. The other variation of the test I have considered is simply changing the certificate as we wish to, but that will require coordination.

Comment: On subject versus SAN, it may well be as you describe. I'm only just getting to grips with the whole certificate thing, and fighting my way through arcane tools and spotty documentation.

Comment: IBM MQ does not validate that the host name or IP that you specify to connect to matches the cert presented.   On the queue manager side the SVRCONN has a field called SSLPEER which you can fill in with a value you want to match such as `CN=clientcertname,O=Client Company`.  If this is filled in then the client must present a cert you trust based on the CA certs and the DN needs to match what you specify.

Comment: If SSLPEER is blank then you will accept any cert that is trusted based on the issuing CAs you trust.   If SSLCAUTH is set to OPTIONAL and SSLPEER is blank the client doesn't even need to present a cert.

Comment: In the MQ Client side there is a  similar settings to SSLPEER that can be set, if it is set then the queue manager cert must match the DN filter provided. In my experience many client applications don't set this value.  The SSLPEER on either end can also use wild cards for example `CN=myserver*,O=Server Company`.  IBM MQ as far as I am aware ignores the SAN value of a cert and only validates against the Subject.

Comment: Note that in the setup you have the SVRCONN would also normally have MCAUSER filled in with a user on your system that is authorized only to the queue that it needs to put or get from.   If MCAUSER is left blank and there are no CHLAUTH rules blocking it or if CHLAUTH is DISABLED then the client can easily connect to your queue manager as an MQ admin with QMQM authority.

Comment: "The "easy" test would not be so easy as we are a large company and getting any DNS changes is a bit of an undertaking. " You don't need a global DNS change. Just make sure the new name exists on the client box. On Unix it is as easy as editing `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent to the check that a web client does to ensure the server certificate's Common Name must match the name at which the web site, is for an MQ Client application to to set the value it expects in the SSLPEER attribute of it's CLNTCONN definition (or equivalent, say `MQCD.SSLPeerNamePtr/Length` in MQCONNX programmable interface).

Unlike web connections, there is no specific standard, so the MQ Client and MQ back-end queue managers would agree some standard to allow the MQ Client application to know it had connected to the correct queue manager.

There is also the reverse check, where the queue manager can set the SSLPEER value at the queue manager end of the connection and only allow MQ Client applications that provide a certificate with certain values in the Distinguish Name to connect to the queue manager.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now I know to look for SSLPEER.